# Get the start date of the events in The Evens Calendar

Tags: wordpress, events, woocommerce, calendar

I'm using WordPress and I have this recurring event in my calendar. As the event was booked, an email was also sent to customer. Thing is, the date of the event emailed to my customers is the starting date of the recurring event, not the starting date of the booked event. I am using The Events Calendar plugin as well as the Events Calendar PRO.

This is the snippet code I have in my theme's function.php

```
function tribe_add_date_to_order_title( $title, $item ) {

    $event = tribe_events_get_ticket_event( $item['product_id'] );

    if ( $event !== false ) {
        $title .= ' - ' . tribe_get_end_date( $event );
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'tribe_add_date_to_order_title', 100, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get just the date
echo tribe_get_start_time ( $event_id, 'd. F');

// get just the time 
echo tribe_get_start_time ( $event_id, 'H:i');
```

Hope this will Help.